# Clojure: using an If statement as a parameter in a function call, if there are no args, pass nothing

Tags: if-statement, functional-programming, clojure

So I have a function do_stuff that can take 0 or 1 arguments as follows

```clj
(defn do_stuff 
   ([]
    (println "no arguments here"))
   ([arg]
    (println "here's the argument"))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (do_stuff (if args (apply str args))
```

How do I return no argument from the if statement, so that I can print the "no arguments here" string?
Edit: Using the when instead of if returns nil, which is still an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using multi-arity definitions

Apply the lesson you learned from `do_stuff` on `-main`:

```
(defn -main
  ([] (do_stuff))
  ([& args] (do_stuff (apply str args))))
```

#### Externalizing condition using `if` (or `cond`)

An `if` expression without `else` branch still returns `nil` but returning `nil` is not returning nothing.
That is you can't make it with an `if` or `when` expression that it just returns nothing. At least not in functional languages like Clojure is.

You could alternatively externalize your `if` like this:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (if args 
     (do_stuff (apply str args))
     (do_stuff)))
```

#### Using `apply`

@EugenePakhomov's idea:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (apply do_stuff (if args [(apply str args)] [])))
```

But what I think is: How about to put the `(apply str args)` part inside `do_stuff`?

```
(defn do_stuff 
   ([]
    (println "no arguments here"))
   ([& args]
    (let [arg (apply str args)]
      (println "here's the argument"))))
```

Because then you could very elegantly do:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (apply do_stuff args))
```

Comment: As an alternative, one could use `apply` and maybe `cond->` + `conj` if there are multiple arities.

Comment: You mean `(apply do_stuff (if args (apply str args) []))`? True, that's an idea - when one has to return something, one can at least return an empty list and apply over it - then it becomes 'nothing'.